# addEventListener to right click event

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, right-click

I would like to add event listener to a right click event, i know how to deal with a simple click: 
`document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){ });`

What about a right click event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just testing the click type using :
`alert("You pressed button: " + event.button)`

Answer (score 7):

Listen to the [`contextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu) event.

Comment: I am also listening to a click a event, and the problem here, that the program is detecting the right click as a click, how to distinguish between them ?

Comment: @Khouloud "... the program is detecting the right click as a click". No, it doesn't. You are listening to `mousedown` event not the `click` event. Listen to `click` instead of the `mousedown`!

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", event => {
if (event.button == 0) { // left click for mouse
    alert("left click");
} else if (event.button == 1) { // wheel click for mouse
    alert("wheel click");
} else if (event.button == 2){   // right click for mouse
    alert("right click");
}});
```

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button, a `button` property of `1` represents "Auxiliary button pressed, usually the wheel button or the middle button (if present)," and the right mouse button is `2`. This also matches my experience (on Windows 10).

Comment: @DLosc is right, I have modified the code a bit, it passed my local environment testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { background: yellow; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; } 
div {
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div oncontextmenu="myFunction(event)">
<p>Right-click inside this box to see the context menu!
</div>
<script>
function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //do something differant context menu
  alert("You right-clicked inside the div!");
}
</script>
<!--if it helpful visit once http://topprojects.ml for more stuf-->
</body>
</html>
```